# how to update meson version in flatpak builder

Tags: meson-build, gnome-builder

I'm trying to work on a gnome project (Aisleriot). It requires meson, so I installed it using

```
sudo apt install meson
```

That installed version 0.61.2. Unfortunately, the project requires version >= 0.62.0. Next, I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel ninja-build
```

Now meson is at version 0.64.0. Unfortunately, when I run Builder

```
flatpak run org.gnome.Builder
```

and load my project, it still uses meson version 0.61.2. Why is it using this earlier version and how do I tell Builder to use the system version instead?

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400412/how-to-change-meson-version-in-gnome-builder-3-30-1) from 4 years ago, but it talks about a build settings panel, which I couldn't find. Does the build settings panel still exist and how do I display it?

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Builder has a project configuration menu containing the build settings panel you need. Choose the *Configure Project* option in the build pull-down menu beside the hammer icon, which opens a modal window and displays an overview of your build settings.

[image: Build pull-down menu option: configure project]

On the side pane, you will see the *Configurations* section, listing all your build presets:

[image: Configuration entries]

Clicking on one of the configuration entries will display a detailed view of that configuration. You'll want to seek the *Build Environment* setting, where you can change the *Runtime* setting to any environment, including your host machine.

[image: Build environment settings group]

Here, you can modify the environment if you wish. Once you are content, select the *Make Active* button:

[image: "Make Active" button on default configuration page]

While you can build against your host system, seasoned Gnome developers insist on developing within a flatpak environment. It might be easier to install the latest version on the Gnome runtime, `org.gnome.Platform`, and build the project against that. If you want to install the latest version, issue the following commands:

```bash
flatpak remote-add gnome-nightly https://nightly.gnome.org/gnome-nightly.flatpakrepo
flatpak install org.gnome.Platform/<arch>/master
```

where <arch> is your architecture.

After executing these commands, your newly-installed runtime will appear as an option in the *Runtime* setting.

### Supplementary note

If the project has a manifest file, such as [Gnome Weather](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-weather/-/blob/main/org.gnome.Weather.json), you can upgrade all the project's dependencies, i.e., runtime and SDK, in one fell swoop by selecting the *Update Dependencies* action in the same pull-down menu. Gnome Builder will refer to the project's manifest file and download and install the appropriate versions.

[image: Build pull-down menu option: update dependancies]

This procedure may take a while, so do be patient.